# Using list of variables, explain behavoir

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

I have some basic lack of understanding how Mathematica works. Could you please explain to me the following behavior or point me to a resource that will let me understand.

```
vs = {a, b};
Resolve[ForAll[vs, vs \[Element] Reals, 
  Equivalent[a < 0 && a == b, b < 0 && a == b]]]
(* ForAll[{vs}, Element[vs, Reals], 
 Equivalent[a < 0 && a == b, b < 0 && a == b]] *)
```

On the other hand:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, {a, b} \[Element] Reals, 
  Equivalent[a < 0 && a == b, b < 0 && a == b]]]
(* True *)
```

The problem seems to be that Mathematica does not substitute `vs` by `{a,b}`.

In other circumstances, however, it seems to work just fine.

```
Reduce[{a + b == 2, a - b == 0}, vs]
(* a==1 && b==1*)
```

I have very many variables and it would be much more convenient to define some list holding the variables (like `vs` in the above example) and then passing the list to functions, but in some cases this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

```
Attributes[ForAll]
(* {HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected} *)
```

The [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute means that `ForAll` does not evaluate its arguments. This makes sense because $\forall$ [binds variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). Here is an example:

```
x=5;
Resolve[ForAll[x,x>3]]
(* False *)
```

This yields `False` because the `x` in `ForAll` is a bound variable and separate from the `x` defined before. See [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html) for much more info on evaluation.

---

One can override this in various ways. For example using [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html):

```
With[{vs={a,b}},
  Resolve[ForAll[vs,vs ∈ Reals,
                 Equivalent[a<0&&a==b,b<0&&a==b]]]]
(* True *)
```

or using [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
vs={a,b};
Resolve[ForAll[Evaluate[vs],Evaluate[vs ∈ Reals],
               Equivalent[a<0&&a==b,b<0&&a==b]]]
(* True *)
```

I use `With` very often, but I `Evaluate` very rarely. This may be a matter of taste.

Note that one can use `With` also when `vs` was defined earlier in the code, as follows:

```
vs={a,b};

(* ...lots of code... *)

With[{vs=vs},
  Resolve[ForAll[vs,vs ∈ Reals,
                 Equivalent[a<0&&a==b,b<0&&a==b]]]]
(* True *)
```

---

OP mentions that `Reduce` behaves differently. In fact, `Reduce` does not hold:

```
Attributes[Reduce]
(* {Protected} *)
```